# How to open Jenkins JNLP file using JDK 13

Tags: java, jenkins, java-web-start, jnlp

I want to add windows machine as Jenkins slave. one windows machine I have installed JDK 13, but `javaws.exe` file missing from JDK 13.

How to open `slave-agent.jnlp` file in JDK 13?

Thanks
SR

Comment: have a look at [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4091911) thread.

Comment: @michalk thanks I have to install the jdk 8 to make this works. Wish there is a option in jDK 13 to run web start file.

Comment: Do you need to launch via jnlp or can try let Jenkins manage via DCOM? Not tried for Jdk 13 and [you may encounter issues](https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-slaves-plugin/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.adoc), but if you're already stuck ...